# How set custom environment variable for a standalone Blazor WASM app?

Tags: http-headers, blazor, webassembly

Using these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment-via-header) we can easily set custom **environment** per app, but not custom environment **variables**. Is there anything similar but for variables?

Perhaps something like `Blazor-Environment-Variable` with a name and a value using some separator. And then these variables could be used in a usual way (like in a desktop .NET app), through `IConfiguration` and `IOptions`.